# putting an overlay over a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a div with some text and a link tag in it, when i click on the link i would like to have an overlay over the div so the opacity is set to .3 or something and have a little form put over it. Does anyone know how to approach this in jquery?

Comment: overlay will anyway show you over the div right ???

Comment: follow the link i gave as answer, there is lot of discussion there which will be useful to you

Answer (score 1):

You can use my `elementOverlay` plugin:

```
var overlay = $('#yourDiv').elementOverlay();

// some code

overlay.elementOverlay('hide');
```

Plugin code: https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin.jquery.tools/blob/master/Source/Plugins/jquery.griffin.elementoverlay.js

Answer (score 0):

Just make a div of a fixed size, width and position (the same and place as the original) and set It's background color to slightly transparent.